# can error row be inserted in another table in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I need to push data from one table tableA into tableB. Now I am using simple insert script to do this as mentioned below -

Insert into tableB
(col1,col2)
Select col1,col2
From tableA

Now col1 in tableb is primary key. Client wants to insert error row in another error table in case there is any error. The process of insert should not stop. For example if there are 2 rows with the same pk value for col1 of tableA then the first row should be inserted in the tableb and the second row which is pk violation should be inserted in another table which has the same structure. Now I don't understand how to make this happen in SQL server. Whole insert is a atomic transaction this is what is the property of transaction.

Can we some how manage this in catch block.

Comment: I assume by catch block you mean in your stored procedure? A catch block will catch an error in the entire atomic transaction. So...you can't manage this in a catch block doing inserts of multiple rows. You would need to handle this kind of thing at a more granular level. Loops come to mind but depending on the actual rules involved you might be able to use multiple insert statements instead.

Comment: Yes the above insert statement is in sp. Looping will be a very slow process. There are almost 60 million records that needs monthly push.

Comment: Right....that's why I said you could probably do this with 2 insert statements instead of a loop. Hard to offer a lot of suggestion here because there isn't a lot of information about what is happening. First insert rows that will be acceptable. Second insert rows that would violate the PK.

Comment: Hmmm. Will row number() over (partition by col1 order by (select 1)) work and then insert only rows which values are 1. All the rows with value as 2 will be inserted in another error table. But I am thinking will row_number() function work efficent for huge rows

Comment: That is along the lines of what I was thinking. The window function might be a little slow with 60M rows but if this is a monthly task then it shouldn't be a huge problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle this in SSIS quite easily. Successful records go into your desired table, unsuccessful records could go into an error table. My screenshot below is quite basic; but I am loading a flat file that fills a staging table with good records and loads the errorred records into an error table.

[image]

Comment: I never thought it would be that easy

Comment: @Jason better would be if you add answer without SSIS solution. This is alternative/workaround solution you should at least mention that